# Can we add elements in an array dynamically and also print it when the size is unknown, in java

Tags: java, arrays

Adding elements to an array in java ,given the size, is easy to code but doing it dynamically poses a problem .
Ex:

```
   Int a[]= new Int[5];
   a[0]=0;
   a[1]=2;
   a[2]=2;
   a[3]=3;
   a[4]=4;
```

Here(in the above example) we know the size, so I can assign the values. What If don't know how many values I have to add, in some cases it could be 5 and some other it might be 100.
So for such a situation I would need an array which will take input dynamically(as many as I input) or on spot.

My question is how to make an array dynamic  in Java?

It could be done using List, but is there a way using array?

Please help me out

Comment: You might want to add some code examples to illustrate your question.

Comment: no, you´d probably "reinvent" a `ArrayList` if you´d do it with an array.  Also this is not a forum...

Comment: There is no type Int only int or Integer. And the length of an array is fixed upon creation time, but can be found easily using theArray.length

Answer (score 0):

You can't allocate dynamically an array, but you can always create a new one when this one is full. This is a method to call when the array is full. it will return a new array with more elements and will get the elements from the old array:

```
public int[] createNewArray(int[] oldArray){
    int[] newArray = new int[oldArray.length * 2];
    for(int i = 0; i < oldArray.length; i++) {
        newArray[i] = oldArray[i];
    }

    return newArray;
}
```